# Preserve Format of Echo variable in URL with Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding a function to a template in wordpress to link a variable ($location) to a search for all events at that location.  This basically involves creating a link to the site's search results with $location as the search string.  However the problem I am running into is although outside of the URL I can call the $location variable and it preserves the spaces in the location name:

NRS Arena

when I use the variable inside of a url, it comes out as

NRSArena

for my search term.  I really need the term to be formatted as

NRS+Arena
or 
NRS%20Arena

for valid use in the search string.

Here's my code:

```
$html .= html( 'a', array( 'href' => esc_url( get_site_url() . '/?st=event&ls=' . $location . '&location='), 'target' => '_blank' ), $location));
```

So for where

$location = NRS Arena

I want it to output the HTML like so:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mysiteurl.com/?st=event&ls=NRS+Arena&location=">NRS Arena</a>
```

or even a %20 between NRS and Arena would be fine instead of the +

Instead it is outputting:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mysiteurl.com/?st=event&ls=NRSArena&location=">NRS Arena</a>
```

By removing the space between the words in the URL, obviously the site search is not going to work.  I don't understand why the use of $location outside of the URL preserves the space, but inside the URL it does not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ...ls='.url_encode($location).'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. use `rawurlencode` - returns %20

> $html .= html( 'a', array( 'href' => esc_url( get_site_url() . '/?st=event&ls=' . rawurlencode($location) . '&location='), 'target' => '_blank' ), $location));

2. use url_encode - returns +

> $html .= html( 'a', array( 'href' => esc_url( get_site_url() . '/?st=event&ls=' . url_encode($location) . '&location='), 'target' => '_blank' ), $location));

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, although for me at least I had to use urlencode($location), as url_encode($location) broke some formatting on the page for some reason.  Thank you from a self-taught php newb!